# Javascript parameterized strings: replace(RegExp, function) unexpected grouping / matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, parameterization

Regular expressions often eludes me. I am struggling to understand an unexpected result with grouping, and would like someone to tell me:

- Why it is not working as intended
- How I could achieve the expected result

#### Context:

I'm working with strings containing hex color codes. I use `replace()` on that string to "feed" the matched color codes to a function returning HTML - kind of a parameterized string. One of the parameters is ok, but the other matches the whole string?

#### Some code:

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2BR7/) with a simple example (beware: does not take letters as far as hex codes go).

The fiddle's code:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Please enter two hex color codes (digits only)</p>
<input id="colorsInput" type="text"></input>
<button id="booyah">Roll</button>
<p>Teh colorz</p>
<div id="colors"></div>
<p>Teh source</p>
<div id="html"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function parameterizedHtml(p1, p2) {
    return '<div style="background-color:#' + p1 + '; width:50px; height:50px;">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:#' + p2 + '; width:50px; height:50px;">&nbsp;</div>'; 
  }    

  $('#booyah').click(function() {
    var colorsString = $('#colorsInput').val();
    var html = colorsString.replace(/(\d{6}).*(\d{6})/, parameterizedHtml);
    $('#html').text(html);
    $('#colors').html(html);
  });

});
```

#### Output:

```
<div style="background-color:#548423 564212; width:50px; height:50px;">&nbsp;</div><div style="background-color:#548423; width:50px; height:50px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Notice the first `background-color` attribute.

Comment: You use [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for `replace` improperly. It expect 1st parameter to be the whole match, not the 1st submatch which corresponds to 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument `replace` gives to the callback function is the *overall* match. That's then followed by additional arguments for any capture groups. So if you change your function signature to:

```
function parameterizedHtml(match, p1, p2)
```

...it will start working as expected.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2BR7/2/) with the change. I've also changed the regex to `/([a-f0-9]{6}).*([a-f0-9]{6})/i` so it accepts hex, but note that numeric color values are not required to be six digits long. They can also be [three digits long](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color). `#abc` is the same as `#aabbcc`. If you want to accept both, then: `/([a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6}).*([a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6})/i`.

Comment: Excellent! I should have read the manual better, I can't believe I missed that one. - Thank you for the updated RegEx, I already had the `[a-f]` part in mind, but did not think about 3-character color codes, this will come in handy. Bonus question: would you say matching `[a-fA-F0-9]` or casting to lowercase and matching `[a-f0-9]` is better?

Comment: @SilverQuettier: In the above, I used the `i` flag on the regex, which is for a case-insensitive match. So no need to do anything to make the string lowercase. I don't think it much matters whether you use the `i` flag or use `[a-fA-F0-9]`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So your regex is looking for digits, not hex. Assuming you are looking for two color codes in one input, I would go with

^([0-9a-fA-F]{6})[^0-9a-fA-F]*([0-9a-fA-F]{6})

With this, you start with 6 hex chars, then any amount of non hex chars (including none), then another 6 hex chars. This also accounts for upper and lower case hex alphas. And then the parenthesis will capture the first color and second color separately.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However as I stated in the question, this was merely a simple example to showcase the "unexpected matching", and I did not bother with proper hex matching, which was not the root of my mistake. (See T.J.'s answer above.)

Comment: fair enough :). You had me at regex and I missed the rest :(